# How to parse string column to datetime format in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXmww.png)
<-How to format column 'Order Date' to DateTime?
This code below doesn't work :(
It thorws to me exception:
ValueError: time data '04/19/19 08:46' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %X' (match)

```
dates = df['Order Date'] #тут список строк с датой
```

`dates['Datka'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %X')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the time part is not %X formatted.

```
dates['Datka'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```